# Science Fiction Film with a scene where actors dodge huge white crates in futuristic warehouse environment

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of a movie where the only scene I recall is one where the actors are moving through a very large warehouse themed environment. It looks very sterile, mostly shades of white. They enter easily enough but soon they're in danger and need to start dodging these hovering/flying machines moving large white crates of the sort you'd see in a modern warehouse, or dockyard/shipyard.

Any movies with this sort of environment will do as well for inspiration, but I do recall one specifically.

Thanks for all your help.

Updated in response to elaboration questions:
- It was English
- I believe the two trying to escape were a man and a woman
- It was live action
- It was relatively new, definitely made within the last 5 years
- I believe I recall the flying machines being mainly hovering transportation carriers/lifts, with just structural arms like you'd see on a 3 or 4 "fingered" grasping crane attachment, but I can't really be sure as recollection is foggy.

Comment: Was it live action? In English? Where did you see it and when? Can you describe the flying machines? Can you describe any of the actors: where the male or female, race, how many, what they were wearing?

Comment: A fight in a warehouse full of moving equipment and machinery with lots of dodging is a very common movie trope, sci-fi or otherwise.  You'll have to narrow it down for us to even start guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of the [car factory chase scene](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x24non_car-factory-scene_fun) from [Minority Report (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/). It's not a perfect match for your description, but it does take place in a rather clean factory environment with a lot of white.

Comment: This is exactly that I was thinking, but I wasn't able to find any pictures from it showing that scene.

Comment: Agreed - I thought of this or the 2012 Total Recall.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said this is a very vague nugget to go on.

How about Cargo? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381940/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

I don't remember it exactly, but there's a scene where some of the characters have to get through a warehouse-y area on their spaceship which lasts for a decent length of time (15 minutes or so if I recall) where they have to avoid the way the ship is moving around containers. It came out in 2009 which fits the time period.