# MST3K-reviewed science fiction film that involved a chase scene (and I think some ramming) in a warehouse with what looked like floor buffers

Tags: story-identification, movie, mst3k

I was looking at [Science Fiction Film with a scene where actors dodge huge white crates in futuristic warehouse environment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92956/) and a memory popped into my mind of a film reviewed on *Mystery Science Theatre 3000* which involved the hero (and I think a female) driving through a futuristic warehouse (maybe on a spaceship?) in a white vehicle that reminded me of a floor-buffer (maybe it was just the sound of their operation?). He's being chased by some of the bad guys in a similar vehicle. I remember the hosts mocking how it was a very low speed chase. I'm pretty sure there was at least one scene involving the pursuing vehicle trying to nudge the protagonist off-course, but I don't remember any spectacular crashes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is MST3K Episode 820 *Space Mutiny*.  The floor buffer vehicles were referred to in the movie as "Enforcers".

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa42pxJyq64) is a link to the episode on YouTube.  The 'enforcer' 'chase' 'scene' starts around 1:16:53.

RiffTrax also covered the movie in a live show recently.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just couldn't summon it to mind.

Comment: We put our faith in Blast Hardcheese.

Comment: That's "Doctor Lady"!

Comment: @Buzz Roll Fizzlebeef!